# in spring 2.7.17 Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernat

Tags: process

I'm working on Spring boot project. Actually, refactoring code.
And getting this mistake as follows: Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

plzz give the way that i can remove the error